# "'deinitialize()' is deprecated: the default argument to deinitialize(count:) has been removed" warning in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode9, unsafemutablepointer

I'm trying to deinitialize an `UnsafeMutablePointer` with this code:

```
pointer.deinitialize()
```

This has worked fine before, but Xcode 9.3 threw me a warning:

> 'deinitialize()' is deprecated: the default argument to deinitialize(count:) has been removed, please specify the count explicitly

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide the `count` argument explicitly - **it should be the count of the values which you want to deinitialize**.

From [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablepointer/1641720-deinitialize):

> ## deinitialize(count:)
>
> Deinitializes the specified number of values starting at this pointer.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **`count`**
>
> The number of instances to deinitialize. `count` must not be negative.